# Laravel Elixir Public Path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

How can I change Laravel Elixir public path? I change the Laravel root directory to this:

[image]

But when I execute the command `gulp` show this error:

```
Fetching Version Source Files...
   - layout/assets/css/styles.css <-- Not Found  

Saving To...
   - public/build
```

I tried do this in Gulpfile.js, but doesn't work. =/

```
    elixir.config.publicDir = '../';

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
  //  mix.styles('styles.css', 'public/layout/assets/css')
    mix.version(['../layout/assets/css/styles.css']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the destination path (and source path, an optional parameter here set to null) in mix.styles:

```
mix.styles('styles.css', 'layout/assets/css', null)
```

I'm not sure what your folder structure is. When the layout folder is in your public folder you can of course change the path to public/layout/assets/css.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the destination folder by adding elixir.config into your gulpfile.js.

Also you can change other laravel-elixir properties with this command. Proper name of the property you will find in /node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/Config.js file.

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

//Change laravel elixir public path
elixir.config.publicPath = "layout/assets";

elixir((mix) => {
    mix.styles('styles.css')
});
```